# With all respect ..but Why linux sucks so much on gaming?

Tags: games, performance

I mean on windows 10 i play left4dead 2 full res,full detail maxed everything and it plays it fluently and nice.
On ubuntu,xubuntu,kubuntu it sucks so much that i must lower many settings to make it even playable and still the moving is not fluent sometimes.
We talk about 3-4 times slower at least.
My graphics card is an Amd radeon r7 200 and i have installed amd proprietary graphics drivers. 
Why ? so many years why you can't focus on something that matters ? and every linux programmer works in seperate projects that finally makes no sense at all ?

Comment: "...something that matters..." is your opinion and is, perhaps, not shared by all of us.

Comment: there are people who enjoy gaming on Linux :-)

Comment: You should blame Microsoft for pushing their proprietary DirectX11 instead of working on OpenGL specifications and improvements. The same applies for Microsofts proprietary office document formats instead of supporting the open document format.

Comment: Because GNU/Linux user share (not server share) is around 1 % and game makers know that 1 % of clients can be ignored and not ignoring them would require more expensive programmers  time to port it. This will change when GNU/Linux user share goes over 5 % IMHO. And it will now that Windows shows too many "do not turn off your computer, it will turn off automatically" and that lasts for minutes and you need to enter fast and can't.

Answer (score 2):

- According to Valve [Left 4 Dead 2](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/02/valve_games_faster_on_linux/) runs 16% better on Linux than on Windows when they ported it using OpenGL.
- On [steamcommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/828938354907979013/) a user test Mint and W7. He used "bublebee" to get better perfomance than on W7. But the latest nVidia drivers he used and  "gamebooster" make W7 top the Linux version with native drivers.
- [Gamingonlinux](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/how-does-left-4-dead-2-perform-on-ubuntu-1304-compared-to-windows-8.2457) have a L4D2 comparision video (13.04 versus W8) 
  https://youtu.be/2pdEftFFG_I  and here a new one: https://youtu.be/QgfCjvPSmVI and 13.04 wins. In the video'
  s are details about how the test was done.

Difference between you and all these: you have an AMD and those test have all been done with an nVidia card.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the used driver. Two drivers exist:

- "radeon", an open source driver
- "fglrx", a proprietary driver that offers a higher performance

You can check this in the "Software and Updates" system settings. You'll find an "Additional drivers" tab where you can select the driver to use.